# Подкючение свитча и роутрера в одну сеть

Tags: сеть, администрирование

Есть коммутатор (свитч) и роутер. Как их можно подключить так, что бы и беспроводные устрояства с роутера, и проводные со свитча были в одной локальной сети и был доступ ко всем устройствам?

Если подключать свитч к роутеру, потянет ли роутер нагрузку из 32 устройств? Не уверен. А если наоборот, будут ли доступны устройства, подключенние к роутеру с устройств подключенных к свитчу?

Comment: Если подключить свитч к wan роутера, то устройства будут в разных сетях.

Comment: Роутеру практически фиолетово сколько у него клиентов. клиент - это одна запись в таблице dhcp (при условии выдачи ip роутером), а она маленькая. вопрос производительности роутера стоит рассматривать только в ключе суммарного трафика всех клиентов (хватает ли проца роутера на обработку потока) и количества открытых соединений (что бы хватало таблицы NAT). И один клиент может создать нагрузку с которой роутер не справится.

Comment: В большинстве случаев с домашними роутерами достаточно воткнуть коммутатор в один из портов локальной сети роутера, и всё заработает. Сразу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку модели не указаны, то вариантов много.

1. Если роутер умеет на LAN и на WiFi раздавать разные подсети - это следует отключить. В случае независимой настройки - например, сформировать два разных DHCP-скопа из одной подсети (скажем, 192.168.0.10..100 для проводной сети и 192.168.0.110..200 для беспроводной, маска /24). Иначе сегменты не будут видеть друг друга напрямую (скажем, в сетевом окружении) без WINS/DNS-сервера. Хотя доступ прямым указанием адреса или статическим соответствием (HOSTS) будет (маршрутизацию же роутер обеспечит, ибо его локальный(е) адрес(а) будет(ут) у клиентов дефолтными шлюзами). Впрочем, такие модели/прошивки нечасты, и, как правило, по интерфейсу сразу видно, что это оборудование ни разу не для начинающих.
2. Если роутер раздаёт на оба интерфейса одну и ту же подсеть, на клиентах для взаимной видимости никаких особых настроек (кроме включения на интерфейсе необходимых клиентов/служб и настройки файрвола/категории сети) не требуется. А на роутере надо проверить наличие следующих настроек (впрочем, эти настройки тоже бывают в прошивке нечасто).

   а) Маршрутизация бродкастов. Если подобная настройка есть - следует разрешить. Иначе сегменты не будут "видеть" друг друга.

   б) Маршрутизация мультикастов. Если подобная настройка есть - следует разрешить. Иначе некоторые сервисы будут недоступны.

   в) Изолированные сети. Если подобная настройка есть - её следует отключить. Иначе будут недоступны не только сегмент с другой средой передачи, но и проводные сегменты, подключенные к разным LAN-портам, не будут доступны друг другу.

С точки зрения производительности по трафику - все проводные клиенты, подключенные в свич, и через него уже в роутер, делят производительность одного LAN-порта. В этом смысле количество клиентов неважно. А вот с точки зрения переполнения ARP-таблицы и NAT-таблицы это разные клиенты. И для роутера начального уровня 32 клиента - это многовато. Даже много...

Answer (score 0):

Подключать нужно свитч к lan портам роутера.

Устройства, которые висят на свитче между собой не будут через роутер взаимодействовать.
Если подключить свитч к wan роутера, то устройства будут в разных сетях. Устройства будут доступны при отключении NAT в роутере